# When I try to pip install catalyst I get this error message? What could the problem be?

Tags: python, catalyst

I get an error when trying to pip install catalyst by enigma.

I've tried upgrading setuptools. I've upgraded my pip.

```
 ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: * Using Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58)
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    * Found conda env: ``/Users/Chris/anaconda3``
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/pk/qv8wtd1n193fzk2ryjc7y2rm0000gn/T/pip-install-fx45b1u3/tables/setup.py", line 597, in <module>
        hdf5_version = get_hdf5_version(hdf5_header)
      File "/private/var/folders/pk/qv8wtd1n193fzk2ryjc7y2rm0000gn/T/pip-install-fx45b1u3/tables/setup.py", line 350, in get_hdf5_version
        major_version = int(re.split("\s*", line)[2])
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pk/qv8wtd1n193fzk2ryjc7y2rm0000gn/T/pip-install-fx45b1u3/tables/
```

I expect this to install without this error.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv for this installation?